# How can you change the apple watch system text size on the simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, apple-watch, text-size

On an actual apple watch you can change the system font size, just like you can on the iPhone itself.

In doing so it's hi lighted a bug with what I was doing trying to get a timer interface object displaying at a smaller than standard size. I'm trying to test this on the simulator though and unfortunately you cannot seem to access the system text size on there. The apple watch app on the iPhone in the simulator doesn't show anything, and the apple watch simulator itself obviously just shows a black screen when not showing your app.

Is this just something that you cannot test on the simulator at the moment?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that don't work in the simulator (yet). For example speech input, correct synchronization of NSUserDefaults, etc. You may file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) for your problem.